# Is a hyphen-split-word one word or mutiple words when CamelCasing it?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, camelcasing

For example, `BuiltinStuff` or `BuiltInStuff`, which one is the correct class naming in Java?

Comment: This is fearly off topic, SO is for help on coding problems...

Comment: Naming conventions are important coding problems.

Comment: Do you mean built-in, though..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My vote is on `BuildInStuff`.

"buildin" isn't a word.